# How to renumber a numbered column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel formatted as a number column (from 1 to 200). Now I want that column to be numbered from 201 to 400 instead. Can someone please help me on how to do it **without** going through each cell and changing the number there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cells with 1 and 2 simply type 201 and 202, select these two cells.

Click with the mouse on the handle at the bottom right of these two cells, hold left mouse key and drag the mouse down until 400 is reached.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you - specifically explaining with a demo.

Answer (score 2):

If one has Excel O365, just remove all values and in your top cell use:

```
=SEQUENCE(200,,200)
```

Makes it super easy to adjust.

Otherwise just change the top cell to 200 and double click the cell's bottom-right square for quick fill.